# The dropdown caret does not appear

Tags: bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I have this piece of code in a Boostrap 4 site:

```
<div class="btn-group mb-2 mr-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see a page that has this code in:

http://demo.riktheme.com/xvito/top-menu/dropdown.html

at the `Split Button Dropdowns` section.

As you can see, the caret is not shown.

The code is pretty much the same as https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/ where the caret does appear.

By using development tools, I see that the `::after` element does not appear after `<span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>` tag.

What is it going on?

Regads
Jaime

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found the `::after` also missing in my css. So, I copied what I found in the [Bootstrap 4.5 docs on Dropdowns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/) using the Dev Tools Inspector and tweaked that a bit. This worked for me. Hopefully, it'll help you.

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5em;
  vertical-align: .25em;
  content: "";
  border-top: .3em solid;
  border-right: .3em solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: .3em solid transparent;
}
```